# when I install Enterprise app in phone6s with iOS 9.2, but I can't find profiles in General?

Tags: ios, enterprise, profiles

when I install  Enterprise app in phone6s with iOS 9.2,  but  I can't find profiles in General? Now I can't open the app!  I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34367869/1956299

Steps for Trust on iOS 9.2:

- Go to "Settings"
- Tap on "General"
- Tap on "Device Managment"
- Tap on "your Profile" (ex: balu corp)
- Tap on Trust 'your Profile'
- Tap on Trust.

Comment: but I can't find Profiles & Device Management in General list