# iOS 9.2 : Not able to trust the Application manually, No Profile option available

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9.2, iphone-security

After Updating to iOS 9.2, we are not able to see the 'profile' section in 'general' option.

I'm trying to test my app on my iPhone but when it runs it gives me a security error "Untrusted Developer" on my iPhone. I have no device profile setting on iOS or a trust button.

Does anyone know how to get by this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260237/when-i-install-enterprise-app-in-phone6s-with-ios-9-2-but-i-cant-find-profiles](http://here)

Steps for Trust on iOS 9.2:

Go to "Settings"

Tap on "General"

Tap on "Device Managment"

Tap on "your Profile" (ex: balu corp)

Tap on Trust 'your Profile'
Tap on Trust.

I believe it references this question but I am not sure where the answer went.